# invalid use of void expression - Adding 2 pointers of different type using typecasting

Tags: c, pointers, casting, type-conversion

So I have three pointer variables, *segbase, *offset and *data. segbase and data are of the type void but offset is int.

What I want to achieve is to - Take the memory address to which segbase is pointing, add the offset to it and copy the resulting memory address to data.

Since segbase and data are not pointers of type integer, it makes sense to typecast them. However, I get the error "Invalid use of void expression" on the line `(int*)*data = (int*)*segbase + *offset;`

```
int main()
{
    void *segbase;
    int *offset;
    void *data;

printf("\nAddress of segbase = %u", segbase);
printf("\nAddress of offset = %u", offset);
printf("\nAddress of data = %u", data);

printf("Now performing the function");

(int*)*data = (int*)*segbase + *offset;

printf("\nAddress of data = %u", data);

}
```

Comment: ***NEVER cast a pointer to `int`.*** If you want to increase a pointer by a number of bytes, cast it to `char*` whose target size is always one byte. Then assign it to the void pointer with no casts on the left-hand side.

Comment: What do you suggest that i do to achieve the intended result then?

Comment: You say offset is into but you show it as int*

Comment: I would suggest to **think** about what your code does. Hint: a typecast-expression is not an lvalue.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want, if offset is a byte offset, is

```
data = (void*)((char*)segbase + *offset);
```

Some C compilers handle offseting void* pointers as if they were char*, in which case it's

```
data = segbase + *offset;
```

Are you sure offset is also a pointer and not a plain int?

Comment: You should still never do arithmetic with a void*, even if the compiler you happen to be using doesn't complain. GCC for example will complain with -pedantic.